# List of people who liked my page

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-javascript-sdk

Is that possible to know the list of people, who liked my page using Facebook Graph API call? If so - which one call is needed and which persmissions I should request?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, this is not possible, and as far as I know never was.